# In Blender, how to define the Text Box size using Python Script on the text editor?

Tags: python, blender

In Blender, how to define the Text Box size using Python Script on the text editor? For example, I want to input size x = 1.5, y = 2, Offset x = -0.75, y = 0.

[image]